# grub-common fix fail

Tags: apt, dpkg

I have a problem with `apt-get`. Some mistake happened when I tried to update the system and when I try to fix it with `apt-get install -f` it fails with this message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
    grub-common
Suggested packages:
    multiboot-doc grub-emu xorriso desktop-base
The following packages will be upgraded:
    grub-common
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
24 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,706 kB of archives.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 315805 files and directories currently installed.)
preparing to unpack .../grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop grub-common.service: Unit grub-common.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
Failed to stop grub-common.service: Unit grub-common.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 subprocess new pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
update-rc.d: warning: start and stop actions are no longer supported; falling back to defaults
Failed to start grub-common.service: Unit grub-common.service not found.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "start" failed.
dpkg: error while cleaning up:
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/grub-common_2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

If I check the status of the service with `service grub-common status` I get this:

```
grub-common.service
  Loaded: not-found (Reason: Not a directory)
  Active: inactive (dead)
```

And I searched the grub-common with `apt search "grub-" |grep inst` I get this:

```
grub-gfxpayload-lists/xenial,now 0.7 amd64 [installed]
   Handles update-grub for ec2 instances
grub-pc/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
grub-pc-bin/xenial-updates,now 2.02~beta2-36ubuntu3.1 amd64 [installed]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please post the output of `service grub-common status`.

Comment: `grub-common.service
   Loaded: not-found (Reason: Not a directory)
   Active: inactive (dead)`

Comment: I will edit your question to include the output. Please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/805583/edit) it again to include the output of `apt search "grub-" | grep inst`. Also, it seems that the ouput of `apt-get install -f` is partial. I think the first part is missing... could you add it as well? Thank you.

Comment: Add the required information inside the question, not in the comments. :)

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto I have done it as you asked ,thank you for help me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Explanation

```
Failed to stop grub-common.service: Unit grub-common.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript grub-common, action "stop" failed.
dpkg: warning: subprocess old pre-removal script returned error exit status 5
dpkg: trying script from the new package instead ...
```

The package manager is trying to stop the `grub-common` service, however your system is in an inconsistent state and it fails. The pre-removal script of `grub-common` is located here:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info/grub-common.prerm
```

It ends with the following part, on my system:

```
# Automatically added by dh_installinit
if [ -x "/etc/init.d/grub-common" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/grub-common.conf" ]; then
        invoke-rc.d grub-common stop || exit $?
fi
# End automatically added section
```

As you can see, it is testing for the presence of either one of two files (`/etc/init.d/grub-common` and `/etc/init/grub-common.conf`) and executing `invoke-rc.d grub-common stop` if they are there. **This commands is failing.**

## Directions

Rename the aforementioned files to keep them but "deactivate" them:

```
sudo mv /etc/init.d/grub-common /etc/init.d/grub-common.bak
sudo mv /etc/init/grub-common.conf /etc/init/grub-common.conf.bak
```

If one of these two commands fails, do not worry.

After this step, you should be able to fix the packages with:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: Thank you for help,you answer is all right.And another question ,why I remed the line `if [ -x "/etc/init.d/grub-common" ] || [ -e "/etc/init/grub-common.conf" ]; then
        invoke-rc.d grub-common stop || exit $?
fi   `,it does not work?

Comment: @user6298426 It should work also if you simply remove those lines, however they might be re-added later by the system. I wrote the approach of renaming the old files because it doesn't have this problem.

Comment: This answer worked perfectly for me: Ubuntu 16.04